# What is the url without mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, content-management-system

There is one open source CMS which is with MVC model and in the .httaccess there is

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

So let say that url is htpp://site.com/admin/settings

There is folder named **controllers** and in it is **file admin_settings.php**

How to get the full url i try this but it dosent work
htpp://site.com/index.php?:admin_sesstings.php

// and since its a MVC we access everething from index.php

I have seen something like this index.php?url={filename}

but in here is different

Comment: You need to look that up in the documentation of the CMS of which you haven't shared any specification.

Comment: there no documentations.The CMS name is sharetronix

Comment: I suggest you contact the vendor support for your issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shoukld be addressed to sharetronix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this reads if requested is NOT FILE and is NOT DIRECTORY...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Meaning that **if you actually request an existing file it will be served "as is".**

So, you should point your browser to `http://site.com/controllers/admin_settings.php` and your file will be served.

Comment: @Marian Petrov is the controllers folder publicly visible (bellow the www or html folder) or does your vendor put the controllers folder above the www in order to achieve higher security? What do your logs show? What error do you get trying my suggestion? Help us help you (giving us details on what's wrong).

Comment: @Marian Petrov that error would make sense in the case the following path `/controllers/admin_settings.php` would not exist on the root folder. Is it on the root folder or bellow?

Comment: the error was because in the system folder there was .httaccses deny from all. The full is site.com/system/controllers/admin_settings.php

Answer (score 2):

Here's the actual translation line by line:

If the requested URI doesn't point to an actual, real, existing *file* on the disk:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

... and if the requested URI doesn't point to an actual, real, existing *folder* on the disk:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then whatever it is, redirect the whole URI `^(.*)$` to `index.php` and re-add the query string (nota: just adding the `QSA` directive should do the same but faster than adding manually `%{QUERY_STRING}`):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
```

If you arrived at this point this means that either the URI points to a real, actual file of the system, or a real, actual folder of the system, so: whatever is, add and authorization password: `%{HTTP:Authorization}`:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Now you can say you have all explained line by line!

---

And please avoid horrible things like "since its a MVC u access" because:

- it's lazyness
- it may be understood like "i don't want to make any effort here please gimme an answer, and I'll leave, coz' i don't care of this site"